# Mailer and resque_mailer failling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, resque

I'm a few days trying to use resque and [resque_mailer gem](https://github.com/zapnap/resque_mailer) and after all the setup issues I finally stoped at this one:

```
ArgumentError
Error
wrong number of arguments (6 for 4)
/app/mailers/notification_mailer.rb:25:in `notificate_used_issues'
```

I call the method this way:

```
@group.users do |user|
     NotificationMailer.notificate_used_issues(@itens,@itens,@itens,@itens,@itens,@itens).deliver
end
```

On the mailer:

```
def notificate_used_issues(itens,itens,itens,itens,itens,itens)
    @itenx = itens
    ...   
    @itenx = itens
    @email = itens
    mail bcc: @email,
         subject: " #{@itenx} of #{@itenx}!"
end
```

detail -> if I use **deliver! method** it sends the mail correctly, but of course not using the redis

Any helper soul?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your NotificationMailer class? At least the method containing line 25?

Comment: Like I said it works, but not with the resque-mailer

Comment: If this is deployed to production, have you made sure to restart your resque workers? They may still be using an older version of the `notificate_used_issues` method that might have only used 4 parameters instead of 6?

Comment: ty dude, but I almost sure that I did restart the pc ...  anyway gonna try one more time, and it isnt in production yet